# expire application_controller cached method from API controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

i have the following method on application_controller:

controllers/application_controller.rb

```
def set_footer_sponsored_links
  @sponsored_links = Rails.cache.fetch("sponsored_links", expires_in: 240.hours) {
        ContentGroup.sponsored_links
      }
end
```

This sponsored_links (*ContentGroup.sponsored_links*) are created and updated via API:

controllers/api/v1/sponsored_links_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::FooterSponsoredLinksController < Api::V1::ApiController
  before_filter :set_sponsored_link, only: [:destroy, :update, :show]

  def create
    sponsored_link = SponsoredLink.create(sponsored_link_params)
    respond_with :api, sponsored_link
  end
  def update
    @sponsored_link.update(sponsored_link_params)
    respond_with :api, @sponsored_link
  end
```

What i need is to set an expire cache method or similar that, from the API, expires cache on the method on application_controller whenever :create, :update or :destroy are called.
Any idea how to accomplish so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a private method in your `Api::V1::FooterSponsoredLinksController` called `expire_links`:

```
...

private

def expire_links
  Rails.cache.delete('sponsored_links')
end
```

Then add a `before_filter` for that method like this:

```
before_filter :expire_links, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: this made it. Thanks @dhouty

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a cache key that includes the maximum `updated_at` `DateTime` like so:

```
def set_footer_sponsored_links
  @sponsored_links = Rails.cache.fetch("sponsored_links-#{SponsoredLink.maximum(:updated_at).try(:utc).try(:to_s, :number)}", expires_in: 240.hours) {
        ContentGroup.sponsored_links
      }
end
```